# Listing of files recursively with modified time in tree-like format

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I'm looking for a *single command* to list all files recursively from a given directory along with its modified time.  It would also be nice if it can produce output in a tree-like format as produced by *tree* command.

**NOTE:** I'm running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.

**EDIT:** The option `-D` of *tree* command prints *only* the date part of the last modification time for past years, though it display date with time for *current year*.  Here, in this case, I'm expecting to print date with time for past years as well.

Comment: You want to show in seconds?

Comment: @quanta: In my case, precision upto *minutes* is enough.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I'm looking for a single command to list all files recursively from a
>   given directory along with its modified time.

```
$ find /path/to/folder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l --time-style="+%F %T"
```

> It would also be nice if it can produce output in a tree-like format
>   as produced by tree command.
>   In my case, precision upto minutes is enough.

On my CentOS, Gentoo, ... `-D` option is already showed in minutes:

```
$ tree -D
.
├── [Jul 26 14:41]  LICENSE
├── [Jul 26 14:41]  manifests
│   ├── [Oct 10 16:30]  defines
│   │   └── [Jul 26 14:41]  redis source.pp
│   └── [Jul 26 14:41]  init.pp
├── [Jul 26 14:41]  README
└── [Jul 26 14:41]  templates
    ├── [Jul 26 14:41]  redis.conf.erb
    └── [Jul 26 14:41]  redis-server.erb

3 directories, 6 files
```

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Just now I'm also discovering that if the modified date is *not* a current year, then it is showing only date part without timestamp, as `Mon dd yyyy`.

Comment: Any ideas to make it to display date with time for past years in tree-format style?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way but edit source code and recompile the `tree` command.

Comment: Though there is no complete answer/solution provided here, atleast the syntax `find /path/to/folder ...` was helpful. Thus accepting this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

This command lists recursively all files in a given directory with their full modification time:

```
ls -Rl --time-style=long-iso /path/to/directory
```

There's no `tree`-like output in `ls` but this is pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this could be a starting point for your solution:

```
\tree -nf  | awk '{printf $0} {system("stat -c \" [ %y ]\" " $NF )}'| sed -e 's#\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*#\1 ]#g'  2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Version 1.6.0 (05/24/11), tree supports the `--timefmt[=]format` option. (`-D` option outputs strange results, some lines have no hour and minute, and some lines have no year)
For example:

```
./tree --timefmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S'

[2024-03-19_19:50:43]  .
├── [2024-02-20_16:43:06]  a
├── [2023-12-27_14:20:23]  b
├── [2023-06-06_20:54:17]  c
├── [2023-09-17_19:49:48]  d
├── [2023-12-27_14:21:24]  e
├── [2024-02-12_21:23:56]  f
├── [2024-02-12_23:03:05]  g
├── [2024-02-26_20:50:12]  h
└── [2024-02-25_18:47:28]  i

1 directory, 9 files
```